# How can a Arduino (5v) power a device that operates on >12v?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage

Say I buy a device that requires 25 volts to function, but I want to control it using my 5v arduino. How would I go about powering/controlling higher voltage devices?

Comment: It depends on the 25V device you're writing about.  Post a link to it, please.

Comment: this is mostly a theoretical question.. using an arduino, how would I power a device that requires a much higher voltage than the 5v supplied by the arduino?

Comment: Are you actually wanting to power it? What is the current that would need to be provided? Or are you just wanting to control it via a relay or something?

Comment: @Kellenjb After thinking about this for a while, I just want to control the flow of a 12v device using the arduino

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's possible, and it's usually done by [step-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) (boost) converters. These converters are based on the principle that inductors react to sudden changes in their current with a high voltage. So, an inductor is put in series with the supply and switched (here the name Switching Mode Power Supply, SMPS) between a short circuit and the load. When the switch opens, the inductor has to discharge the stored energy and it does that creating an opposite voltage than the one it's charged with.

Another efficient way is also the [charge pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_pump), where capacitors are charged at the supply voltage (5V in this case) and then put in series with the supply rail to generate the higher voltage. It's commonly used to double voltage, but different ratios are possible.

All these circuits create a pulsed output voltage; it can be filtered afterwards to give it a more stable shape if required.

Comment: +1, enjoyed your time scale: "*tomorrow I'll make it better*" :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh that's also part of engineering: projects get delayed and, sometimes, cancelled ;)

Answer (score 4):

An example of the answer by Petteri Hietavirta can be seen at the link.

[Yenka Model to play with.](http://www.rodsdot.com/yenka/optoisolator.yka)

[image]

Opto-Isolator is a safe way to go to avoid frying the Arduino.

Comment: That *controls* the higher voltage device, doesn't *power* it.

Comment: tester said power or **control**

Comment: As I understand it he wants to power *and* control it

Answer (score 1):

If you have correct voltage supply available for the device you want to control with Arduino, check [optoisolators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator).

With that your Arduino should be safe from high voltage but still able to control the device.

Comment: That *controls* the higher voltage device, doesn't *power* it.

Comment: Why the downvote?  OP said specifically control.

Answer (score 0):

You can also boost your voltage by external circuit designed for specific values as @clabacchio said. I think [this link](http://www.linear.com/products/step-up_%28boost%29_regulators) will help you much.

And [this video](http://eevblog.org/video/EEVblog139-SelectAconverter-480x272.m4v) tells you a story of an engineer and his journey to find the best voltage boost for his needs.